# Getting error redirecting on hold call into agent conference

Tags: express, twilio, twilio-twiml

Here is my current flow. A call comes in and is put into a queue.

An agent becomes available and calls `connect` from the client Javascript application.

That response sees (via custom params) that an agent is trying to connect and returns this response

```js
const toNumber = requestBody.To
twimlVR.dial({ callerId }).conference(
  {
    participantLabel: "agent",
    beep: "false",
    waitUrl: "",
    startConferenceOnEnter: true,
    endConferenceOnExit: true,
    statusCallbackEvent: ["join", "leave"],
    statusCallback: `${process.env.BASE_API_URL}/dialer/conference-status?to=${toNumber}`, // the statusCallback will be used to connect the outgoing lead number participant to the conference
  },
  `${requestBody.identity}` // unique conference name
)
return twimlVR.toString()
```

The agents device connects to a conference and the `statusCallback` is called which responds this way

```js
if (
  body.StatusCallbackEvent === "participant-join" &&
  body.ParticipantLabel === "agent"
) {
  // dials the lead number participant into the conference when the agent joins the conference
  const conference = res.locals.twilioClient.conferences(body.ConferenceSid)
  const conferenceParticipants = conference.participants
  const consultationQueue = await res.locals.twilioClient.queues
    .list()
    .then((queues: QueueInstance[]) => {
      return queues.filter(
        (queue: QueueInstance) =>
          queue.friendlyName === "consultation" && queue.currentSize > 0
      )
    })
  if (consultationQueue.length > 0) {
    const onHoldCall = await res.locals.twilioClient
      .queues(consultationQueue[0].sid)
      .members("Front")
      .fetch()
    onHoldCall.update({
      url: `${process.env.BASE_API_URL}/dialer/join-conference?conferenceName=${body.FriendlyName}`,
      method: "GET",
    })
  } else {
    conferenceParticipants.create({
      to: req.query.to,
      from: twilioConfig.callerId,
      beep: "onEnter",
      label: "lead",
      endConferenceOnExit: true,
    })
  }
}
```

It updates the `onHoldCall` to a new URL which in turn response with this

```js
const twimlVR = new twiml.VoiceResponse()
twimlVR.dial().conference(
  {
    participantLabel: "lead",
    beep: "true",
    waitUrl: "",
    startConferenceOnEnter: true,
    endConferenceOnExit: true,
    statusCallbackEvent: ["join", "leave"],
    statusCallback: `${process.env.BASE_API_URL}/dialer/conference-status`, // the statusCallback will be used to connect the outgoing lead number participant to the conference
  },
  `${req.query.conferenceName}` // unique conference name
)
return twimlVR.toString()
```

At the end of this I'm expecting the onHold call to be moved into the conference that the agent is also in, but I get an unexpected error from twilio and the call ends for the incoming on hold call. Am I missing something here?

I've verified that the conference name is the same on both sides, and as far as I understand I don't need to do anything with participants to make this work.

Answer (score 0):

This setup is correct and the code is accurate, I just discovered I was getting a 404 on that endpoint because it was marked as a post and not a get in the express router XD